# Send Email to each recipient stored into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, email

I'm trying to send an email using the sql server email option, I already can send an email, but now I'm trying to send that email to dynamic recipients, for example... I have the following table:

> ID | Email
>   ..1| example@example.com
>   ..2| example2@example.com

With my code I need to do the following thing:

```
@recipients = 'example@example.com; example2@example.com;'
```

What I want to do is to select that emails from a table, so if I edit one email I dont have to change anything about my code, just update the information from my table.

I'm thinking maybe do it by using a var, something like:

```
Declare @emails nvarchar(max)
set @email = query
then do something like a foreach (foreach email in @emails) or something like that (in T-SQL of course...)
```

Is this possible? Or what another solution can I try?

Answer (score 1):

Recipients has the option to add more than one email in the same line, so maybe the easier way to solve your problem is select all the emails and then join them separated with a ;. If you thing that this is a good option you should try this code:

```
Declare @Emails nvarchar(MAX)

Select @Emails = coalesce(@Emails + ';', '') + Email from yourTable
//Your output should be: example@example.com;example2@example.com
```

Then all you need to do this:

```
@recipients = @Emails
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the strings in the column, so something like this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.exampleTable (
    id int,
    email varchar(200)
    )

INSERT INTO dbo.exampleTable VALUES (1,'a@a'),(2,'b@b')

SELECT stuff( (SELECT ';'+email
               FROM dbo.exampleTable 
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
            ,1,1,'')
```

There are also some other ways to do it: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

The result of the query you build or use can be used to set your @email variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a cursor for that

```
DECLARE @email nvarchar(max)
set @email = ''
DECLARE @cursorName CURSOR FOR
SELECT emailColumn FROM tableName
OPEN @cursorName
```

Then you use a loop to concatenate each email

```
FETCH NEXT FROM @cursorName INTO @email   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
   set @email = @email+@cursorName+'; '
END
```